# GWT-Maven only compile gwt.rpc

Tags: maven, gwt

I have a situation where I am debugging via -noserver and it forces me to recompile my gwt application everytime one of my RPC objects changes or I get a serialization error (This is well described in the GWT documentation and I understand why it is happening).

That being said, our project is getting quite big and the compile takes a while to complete, which is slowing down our development process. I have optimzed this as much as I can (Using -draftCompile, only doing a single permutation, and skipping all tests) but it's still pretty slow and I have a pretty beastly computer.

This led me to wonder if a better option here would be to get the compiler to only output the necessary files to make serialization work correctly.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You can do it using maven goals.
In Eclipse "run configurations" I have a specific configuration for that.

```
Goals: gwt:generateAsync gwt:i18n gwt:css
Profiles: dev-ff
```

The gwt:generateAsync goal is for generating your RPC. This is a standard goal with gwt-maven-plugin (assuming you are using it, of course). 
Profiles: dev-ff ensures I'll only generate the code for Firefox.

Here is a part of the maven plugin config. Notice the goals definitions. You'll at least need the servicePattern attribute to tell the plugin where are your RPC interfaces.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${gwt-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test</goal>
                <goal>i18n</goal>
                <goal>css</goal>
                <goal>generateAsync</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin 
                    documentation at codehaus.org -->
    <configuration>
        <servicePattern>**/*RPC.java</servicePattern>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After doing this kind of operation, I often had to open my generated async files to get them in sync with Eclipse. Afterwards we found out we could just delete the gwt-unitCache/ folder in the target/ folder to force the application to use the new RPC classes.

More information about the plugin is [available here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/async.html).

Comment: The `gwt:generateAsync` goal builds the other half of the RPC interface. It does *not* generate the rpc policy file, which is what the question is asking for.